# JS why is my for loop push to array stopping after 1 iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
const say = console.log;

let grid = [];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  grid.push((i = [i, ""]));
  say(i);
}
```

Why does this stop after only 1 iteration, but if I put the push line into a function and call it, it works perfectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the value of `i` to `[0, ""]` which isn't less than `5`

Edit:
To be 100% correct, first `[0, '']++` happens which probably throws an error

Comment: oooo ok i didnt think it would work like that. i was trying to set the aray to the iteration count. i didn't think it would do that lol, ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning i to something that is not a number

```
const say = console.log;

let grid = [];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  grid.push([i, ""]);
  say(i);
}
```

needed to remove the `i = [i, ""]`

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is executed as long as the condition (`i < 5`) is true. In the push statement in your loop the expression `(i = [i, ""])` overwrites the `i` variable. Therefore `i` contains `[ 0, '' ]`.
Then the increment is executed, where javascript typecast `i` back to a `number`, which results in the `NaN` value. The comparison of `NaN < 5` evaluates to false.

TLDR: You should avoid reassigning the variable `i`.

Edit:
included the increment step as @Konrad Linkowsk noted

Comment: To be 100% correct, first `[0, '']++` happens which probably throws an error

Comment: You are right. Forgot about this step.
The `i++` numcasts `i` and numcasting `[0, '']` results in `NaN`. The result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Because after the first iteration

```
the value of i becomes [0, ""]
```

whilst pushing into grid array, the value of "i" is getting modified and loop condition (i.e. [0,""] < 5) is getting failed, hence the loop breaks.